# Drupal dynamic module for responsive slideshow

Tags: drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, drupal-theming

I am currently working on drupal responsive theme.For this I am creating my own custom theme.

For making it responsive I have used twitter bootstrap. I have used carousel plugin for slideshow which works well in html.

The images in the slideshow are static that is I have hard-coded there path.But in drupal I want to choose images dynamically as in wordpress or joomla module.

Is it possible? If it is not than is there any slideshow module for drupal which can solve my problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

FlexSlider is an excellent module for this. Unfortunately it's not quite as configurable as Views Slideshow, but Views Slideshow requires hacking to get it responsive as it inserts width/height attributes directly in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood right, try to add the "img-fluid" class to the image and don't set the width for any container